# Querying in One to many mappings in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have a book entity and a library entity (one library can have multiple books, but each book belongs to only one library). They are defined as follows:

```
public class Library
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "library")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
public class Book
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_Library", nullable=false)
    private Library library;
}
```

I want to find all books which belong to a particular library. One way is to create a `LibraryRepository` as follows:

```
public interface LibraryRepository extends JpaRepository<Library, Long>{}
```

Now I have `findById(Long libraryId)` method that returns a `Library` object with a `List<Book>` in it.

I was wondering if it is possible to create a `BookRepository` and declare a method named `findByLibraryId(Long libraryId)` and let hibernate query the `Book` table by the foreign key `FK_Library`, **without performing any joins**.

Something like this:

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
    public List<Book> findByLibraryId(Long libraryId);
}
```

The above method `findByLibraryId` does perform join. I do not want it to perform a join, since all I want is find all rows which have `library_id` defined by foreign key relationship.

Also is the first method more preferable then second one?

Comment: Why exactly you need this ? You can do this using native query and may be using JPQL also

Comment: Using native query might bind it to specific type of schema.

Comment: Also, in `findById` method of `LibraryRepository` it returns `Library` object with `List<Book>`, but it does not perform join when I see the hibernate generated query. How is this possible?

Comment: @OneToMany by default lazy, so first fetch the library then fetch the books of the library in separte query when getter called. So 2 queries executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@Query` with JPQL to do that

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.library.id = :libraryId")
public List<Book> findByLibraryId(Long libraryId);
```

Comment: Looking from performance side, using `@Query` is better or using LibraryRepository's `findById` method?

Comment: Depends if you want only books of library then use @Query  and if you want Library also  then query in `LibraryRepository` and rather doing two query you do that using one query using @EntityGraph

Answer (score 2):

You could change the @ManyToOne relationship to lazy loading.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

This is the default for OneToMany, thats why you see no join when you search the Library.